# MS Access Update table with 7 Collections Or 1 Array?

Tags: ms-access, vba

So trying to keep this section very brief:
I have two tables. Tbl1 has the financial accounts by year for each company in seperate rows.
Table2 has each company only once and all the financial data is now in one row.
How do i do that? Currently attempting it with Collections have a second attempt going with Arrays.

Hi guys so i have two tables Figs1 and Sabi. Figs1 is set up like: NIF,PeriodEnding, Materials, Depreciation, Non-Trading Income, Total Interest, Pretax Profit, TotalEmpRemu.

So you'll get repeating Company IDs with each each of their financials as the rows.

In Sabi it changes to each company has 1 row and all that data is in columns e.g. PeriodEnding_Latest, PeriodEnding -1, PeriodEnding -2 etc. till -6. I have made a collection for each column in Figs1 and i want to update the table Sabi in the correct order.

So PeriodEnding collection will have {(31/12/2018), (31/12/2017), (31/12/2016), (31/12/2015), (31/12/2014), (31/12/2013)}

Those values need to go to PeriodEnding_Latest, PeriodEnding -1, PeriodEnding -2 etc.

I have the update SQL Statement and filled it with variables:

```
    SQL = "UPDATE SabiFigures1 SET SabiFigures1.[Closing Date Last avail yr] = '& DateFiled1 &', SabiFigures1.[Closing Date Year - 1] = '& DateFiled2 &', " & _
          "SabiFigures1.[Closing Date Year - 2] = '& DateFiled3 &', SabiFigures1.[Closing Date Year - 3] = '& DateFiled4 &', SabiFigures1.[Closing Date Year - 4] = '& DateFiled5 &, " & _
          "SabiFigures1.[Closing Date Year - 5] = '& DateFiled6 &', SabiFigures1.[Material costs th EUR Last avail yr] = '2933', SabiFigures1.[Material costs th EUR Year - 1] " & _
          "= '2791', SabiFigures1.[Material costs th EUR Year - 2] = '3721', SabiFigures1.[Material costs th EUR Year - 3] = '3021', SabiFigures1.[Material costs th EUR Year - 4] " & _
         "= '3005', SabiFigures1.[Material costs th EUR Year - 5] = '1890', SabiFigures1.[Depreciation th EUR Last avail yr] = '49', SabiFigures1.[Depreciation th EUR Year - 1] = " & _
         "'52', SabiFigures1.[Depreciation th EUR Year - 2] = '47', SabiFigures1.[Depreciation th EUR Year - 3] = '42', SabiFigures1.[Depreciation th EUR Year - 4] = '54', " & _
        "SabiFigures1.[Depreciation th EUR Year - 5] = '63', SabiFigures1.[Financial revenue th EUR Last avail yr] = Null, SabiFigures1.[Financial revenue th EUR Year - 1] " & _
        "= Null, SabiFigures1.[Financial revenue th EUR Year - 2] = Null, SabiFigures1.[Financial revenue th EUR Year - 3] = Null, SabiFigures1.[Financial revenue th EUR Year " & _
        "- 4] = Null, SabiFigures1.[Financial revenue th EUR Year - 5] = Null, SabiFigures1.[Financial expenses th EUR Last avail yr] = Null, SabiFigures1.[Financial expenses " & _
       "th EUR Year - 1] = Null, SabiFigures1.[Financial expenses th EUR Year - 2] = Null, SabiFigures1.[Financial expenses th EUR Year - 3] = Null, " & _
       "SabiFigures1.[Financial expenses th EUR Year - 4] = Null, SabiFigures1.[Financial expenses th EUR Year - 5] = Null, SabiFigures1." & _
     "[P/L before tax th EUR Last avail yr] = '407', SabiFigures1.[P/L before tax th EUR Year - 1] = '252', SabiFigures1.[P/L before tax th EUR Year - 2] " & _
     "= '1076', SabiFigures1.[P/L before tax th EUR Year - 3] = '597', SabiFigures1.[P/L before tax th EUR Year - 4] = '329', SabiFigures1.[P/L before tax th EUR Year - 5] = " & _
                                            "'102', SabiFigures1.[Cost of employees th EUR Last avail yr] = '1226', SabiFigures1.[Cost of employees th EUR Year - 1] = '1205', SabiFigures1.[Cost of employees th EUR Year - 2] " & _
   "= '1310', SabiFigures1.[Cost of employees th EUR Year - 3] = '1157', SabiFigures1.[Cost of employees th EUR Year - 4] = '1319', SabiFigures1.[Cost of employees th EUR Year - 5] = '1342' " & _
   "WHERE (((SabiFigures1.[NIF Code])='A01011550'));"
   db.Execute SQL
```

The code pretty much goes to first table: Figs1 and get the first regnumber it will then go to Sabi where i have prepopulated the unqiue NIFs. If it finds a correspondencing NIF in Figs1 and Sabi then it should fill out the variables from the collection however, i dont know how to do variable "variables". E.g. the base structure of the variable should be DateFiled but as it loops through the collection of PeriodEndings it should change from DateFiled1 till Datefiled6.

```
Set rsFigs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM Figs1Ready ORDER BY NIF, PeriodEnding DESC;")
    If Not (rsFigs1.EOF And rsFigs1.BOF) Then
        rsFigs1.MoveFirst
        Do Until rsFigs1.EOF = True
            NIF = rsFigs1!NIF
            Set rsFormat = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM SabiFigures1;")
            If Not (rsFormat.EOF And rsFormat.BOF) Then
                rsFormat.MoveFirst
                Do Until rsFormat.EOF = True
                    nIFF = rsFormat![NIF Code]
                    If NIF = nIFF Then
                        Set qdfDef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("PopulateSabiFigures1")
                        qdfDef.Parameters("NIF: ").Value = nIFF
                        Set rstDef = qdfDef.OpenRecordset()
                        Set PeriodEnding = RSToColl(rstDef, "PeriodEnding")
                        Set Materials1 = RSToColl(rstDef, "Materials")
                        Set Depreciation1 = RSToColl(rstDef, "Depreciation")
                        Set NonTrading1 = RSToColl(rstDef, "Non-Trading Income")
                        Set TotalInterest = RSToColl(rstDef, "Total_Interest_Charges")
                        Set Pretax = RSToColl(rstDef, "Pretax_Profit")
                        Set TotalRemu = RSToColl(rstDef, "Total_Empl_Remu_000")

                        For i = 1 To 6
                        VariableName = "DateFiled" & i
                        Next i

                        For Each Period In PeriodEnding
                            Debug.Print TypeName(Period)
                        Next


                    End If
                           SQL = 'The massive SQL statement above
                           db.Execute SQL
            rsFormat.MoveNext
            Loop
        End If
    rsFigs1.MoveNext
    Loop
End If


rstDef.Close
Set rstDef = Nothing
rsFormat.Close
Set rsFormat = Nothing
rsFigs1.Close
Set rsFigs1 = Nothing
```

Maybe i'm looking at the problem in the wrong way any help and pointers would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. Added some pictures hopefully it helps
[image: Pretty much the layout and design of Figs]
[image: Design and layout of sabi]

To Gustav who first suggested an Array i can do something like this:
This will bring back every year(row) individually. I would like to update a row in one go to save on time instead updating each yearly value. Pretty much updating each row 6 times which would take a lot longer I imagine.

```
Set rsFormat = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM SabiFigures1;")
    If Not (rsFormat.EOF And rsFormat.BOF) Then
        rsFormat.MoveFirst
        Do Until rsFormat.EOF = True
            nIFF = rsFormat![NIF Code]
            Set qdfDef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("PopulateSabiFigures1")
            qdfDef.Parameters("NIF: ").Value = nIFF
            Set rstDef = qdfDef.OpenRecordset()
            rstDef.MoveLast
            rstDef.MoveFirst
            varRecord = rstDef.GetRows(rstDef.RecordCount)
            For intI = 0 To 5 'UBound(varRecord, 2)
                For intJ = 0 To UBound(varRecord, 1)
                    Debug.Print varRecord(intJ, intI)
                Next intJ
            Next intI
                    'whole row updated here after each value of the array is passed to variables for each year and financial value.
            rstDef.Close
            Set rstDef = Nothing
        rsFormat.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
```

Comment: Not at all sure what you are asking, but it may sound as you look for an _array_: `DateFiled(1 To 6)`.

Comment: Hi there ive just added some pics does that help make it easier to understand? Pretty I want to move what is covered over 1 to 10 rows into one row of data

Comment: @Besarion - can you add a TLDR section to the question with 3 sentenses? I have also not managed to understand what you were asking, but it seems interesting.

Comment: Has that helped? Put it at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there so i figured it out. The code is very bulky so anyone who can make it a bit more streamlined and flexible e.g. it the columns i need changed would be much appreciated.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim rsFormat As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsFigs1 As Object
Dim qdfDef As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rstDef As Object
Dim varRecord As Variant
Dim NIF As String
Dim nIFF As String
Dim intI As Integer
Dim intJ As Integer
Dim RegNum, LatestDate, Date1, Date2, Date3, Date4, Date5, LatestMaterial, Material1, Material2, Material3, Material4, Material5, LatestDepreciation, Depreciation1, Depreciation2 As String
Dim Depreciation3, Depreciation4, Depreciation5, LatestTrading, Trading1, Trading2, Trading3, Trading4, Trading5, LatestTotalInterest, TotalInterest1, TotalInterest2, TotalInterest3 As String
Dim TotalInterest4, TotalInterest5, LatestPreTaxProfit, PreTaxProfit1, PreTaxProfit2, PreTaxProfit3, PreTaxProfit4, PreTaxProfit5, LatestTotEmpRem, TotEmpRem1, TotEmpRem2, TotEmpRem3 As String
Dim TotEmpRem4, TotEmpRem5, SQL As String

Set rsFormat = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select [NIF Code] FROM SabiFigures1;")
    If Not (rsFormat.EOF And rsFormat.BOF) Then
        rsFormat.MoveFirst
        Do Until rsFormat.EOF = True
            nIFF = rsFormat![NIF Code]
            Set qdfDef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("PopulateSabiFigures1")
            qdfDef.Parameters("NIF: ").Value = nIFF
            Set rstDef = qdfDef.OpenRecordset()
            rstDef.MoveLast
            rstDef.MoveFirst
            varRecord = rstDef.GetRows(rstDef.RecordCount)
            For intI = 0 To 5
                For intJ = 0 To UBound(varRecord, 1)
                    Debug.Print varRecord(intJ, intI)
                    On Error Resume Next
                    If intI = 0 Then
                        If intJ = 0 Then
                            RegNum = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 1 Then
                            LatestDate = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 2 Then
                            LatestMaterial = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 3 Then
                            LatestDepreciation = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 4 Then
                            LatestTrading = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 5 Then
                            LatestTotalInterest = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 6 Then
                            LatestPreTaxProfit = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 7 Then
                            LatestTotEmpRem = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        Else
                            MsgBox "Error in Loop"
                            Exit Sub
                        End If
                ElseIf intI = 1 Then
                        If intJ = 0 Then
                            RegNum = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 1 Then
                            Date1 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 2 Then
                            Material1 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 3 Then
                            Depreciation1 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 4 Then
                            Trading1 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 5 Then
                            TotalInterest1 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 6 Then
                            PreTaxProfit1 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 7 Then
                            TotEmpRem1 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        Else
                            MsgBox "Error in Loop"
                            Exit Sub
                        End If
                ElseIf intI = 2 Then
                        If intJ = 0 Then
                            RegNum = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 1 Then
                            Date2 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 2 Then
                            Material2 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 3 Then
                            Depreciation2 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 4 Then
                            Trading2 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 5 Then
                            TotalInterest2 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 6 Then
                            PreTaxProfit2 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 7 Then
                            TotEmpRem2 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        Else
                            MsgBox "Error in Loop"
                            Exit Sub
                        End If
                ElseIf intI = 3 Then
                        If intJ = 0 Then
                            RegNum = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 1 Then
                            Date3 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 2 Then
                            Material3 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 3 Then
                            Depreciation3 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 4 Then
                            Trading3 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 5 Then
                            TotalInterest3 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 6 Then
                            PreTaxProfit3 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 7 Then
                            TotEmpRem3 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        Else
                            MsgBox "Error in Loop"
                            Exit Sub
                        End If
                ElseIf intI = 4 Then
                        If intJ = 0 Then
                            RegNum = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 1 Then
                            Date4 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 2 Then
                            Material4 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 3 Then
                            Depreciation4 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 4 Then
                            Trading4 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 5 Then
                            TotalInterest4 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 6 Then
                            PreTaxProfit4 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 7 Then
                            TotEmpRem4 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        Else
                            MsgBox "Error in Loop"
                            Exit Sub
                        End If
                ElseIf intI = 5 Then
                        If intJ = 0 Then
                            RegNum = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 1 Then
                            Date5 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 2 Then
                            Material5 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 3 Then
                            Depreciation5 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 4 Then
                            Trading5 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 5 Then
                            TotalInterest5 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 6 Then
                            PreTaxProfit5 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        ElseIf intJ = 7 Then
                            TotEmpRem5 = varRecord(intJ, intI)
                        Else
                            MsgBox "Error in Loop"
                            Exit Sub
                        End If
                Else
                    MsgBox "Error in Loop"
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                Next intJ

            Next intI
    SQL = "UPDATE SabiFigures1 SET SabiFigures1.[Closing Date Last avail yr] = '" & LatestDate & "', SabiFigures1.[Closing Date Year - 1] = '" & Date1 & "', " & _
          "SabiFigures1.[Closing Date Year - 2] = '" & Date2 & "', SabiFigures1.[Closing Date Year - 3] = '" & Date3 & "', SabiFigures1.[Closing Date Year - 4] = '" & Date4 & "', " & _
          "SabiFigures1.[Closing Date Year - 5] = '" & Date5 & "', SabiFigures1.[Material costs th EUR Last avail yr] = '" & LatestMaterial & "', SabiFigures1.[Material costs th EUR Year - 1] " & _
          "= '" & Material1 & "', SabiFigures1.[Material costs th EUR Year - 2] = '" & Material2 & "', SabiFigures1.[Material costs th EUR Year - 3] = '" & Material3 & "', SabiFigures1.[Material costs th EUR Year - 4] " & _
          "= '" & Material4 & "', SabiFigures1.[Material costs th EUR Year - 5] = '" & Material5 & "', SabiFigures1.[Depreciation th EUR Last avail yr] = '" & LatestDepreciation & "', SabiFigures1.[Depreciation th EUR Year - 1] = " & _
          "'" & Depreciation1 & "', SabiFigures1.[Depreciation th EUR Year - 2] = '" & Depreciation2 & "', SabiFigures1.[Depreciation th EUR Year - 3] = '" & Depreciation3 & "', SabiFigures1.[Depreciation th EUR Year - 4] = '" & Depreciation4 & "', " & _
          "SabiFigures1.[Depreciation th EUR Year - 5] = '" & Depreciation5 & "', SabiFigures1.[Financial revenue th EUR Last avail yr] = '" & LatestTrading & "', SabiFigures1.[Financial revenue th EUR Year - 1] " & _
          "= '" & Trading1 & "', SabiFigures1.[Financial revenue th EUR Year - 2] = '" & Trading2 & "', SabiFigures1.[Financial revenue th EUR Year - 3] = '" & Trading3 & "', SabiFigures1.[Financial revenue th EUR Year " & _
          "- 4] = '" & Trading4 & "', SabiFigures1.[Financial revenue th EUR Year - 5] = '" & Trading5 & "', SabiFigures1.[Financial expenses th EUR Last avail yr] = '" & LatestTotalInterest & "', SabiFigures1.[Financial expenses " & _
          "th EUR Year - 1] = '" & TotalInterest1 & "', SabiFigures1.[Financial expenses th EUR Year - 2] = '" & TotalInterest2 & "', SabiFigures1.[Financial expenses th EUR Year - 3] = '" & TotalInterest3 & "', " & _
          "SabiFigures1.[Financial expenses th EUR Year - 4] = '" & TotalInterest4 & "', SabiFigures1.[Financial expenses th EUR Year - 5] = '" & TotalInterest5 & "', SabiFigures1." & _
          "[P/L before tax th EUR Last avail yr] = '" & LatestPreTaxProfit & "', SabiFigures1.[P/L before tax th EUR Year - 1] = '" & PreTaxProfit1 & "', SabiFigures1.[P/L before tax th EUR Year - 2] " & _
          "= '" & PreTaxProfit2 & "', SabiFigures1.[P/L before tax th EUR Year - 3] = '" & PreTaxProfit3 & "', SabiFigures1.[P/L before tax th EUR Year - 4] = '" & PreTaxProfit4 & "', SabiFigures1.[P/L before tax th EUR Year - 5] = " & _
          "'" & PreTaxProfit5 & "', SabiFigures1.[Cost of employees th EUR Last avail yr] = '" & LatestTotEmpRem & "', SabiFigures1.[Cost of employees th EUR Year - 1] = '" & TotEmpRem1 & "', SabiFigures1.[Cost of employees th EUR Year - 2] " & _
          "= '" & TotEmpRem2 & "', SabiFigures1.[Cost of employees th EUR Year - 3] = '" & TotEmpRem3 & "', SabiFigures1.[Cost of employees th EUR Year - 4] = '" & TotEmpRem4 & "', SabiFigures1.[Cost of employees th EUR Year - 5] = '" & TotEmpRem5 & "' " & _
          "WHERE (((SabiFigures1.[NIF Code])='" & RegNum & "'));"
    db.Execute SQL
    SQL = ""
    RegNum = ""
    LatestDate = ""
    Date1 = ""
    Date2 = ""
    Date3 = ""
    Date4 = ""
    Date5 = ""
    LatestMaterial = ""
    Material1 = ""
    Material2 = ""
    Material3 = ""
    Material4 = ""
    Material5 = ""
    LatestDepreciation = ""
    Depreciation1 = ""
    Depreciation2 = ""
    Depreciation3 = ""
    Depreciation4 = ""
    Depreciation5 = ""
    LatestTrading = ""
    Trading1 = ""
    Trading2 = ""
    Trading3 = ""
    Trading4 = ""
    Trading5 = ""
    LatestTotalInterest = ""
    TotalInterest1 = ""
    TotalInterest2 = ""
    TotalInterest3 = ""
    TotalInterest4 = ""
    TotalInterest5 = ""
    LatestPreTaxProfit = ""
    PreTaxProfit1 = ""
    PreTaxProfit2 = ""
    PreTaxProfit3 = ""
    PreTaxProfit4 = ""
    PreTaxProfit5 = ""
    LatestTotEmpRem = ""
    TotEmpRem1 = ""
    TotEmpRem2 = ""
    TotEmpRem3 = ""
    TotEmpRem4 = ""
    TotEmpRem5 = ""

            'For intI = 6 To UBound(varRecord, 2)
            '    For intJ = 0 To UBound(varRecord, 1)
            '        Debug.Print varRecord(intJ, intI)
            '    Next intJ
            'Next intI

            rstDef.Close
            Set rstDef = Nothing
        rsFormat.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
```